# Какой метод машинного обучения выбрать?

Tags: машинное-обучение

Есть данные в таблице | время|-| давление в баке |. С шагом 0.05 секунд с датчика приходит сигнал о показаниях давления. Данная таблица есть как для штатной ситуации, так и для внештатной ситуации( когда давление выходит из допустимой  нормы). Хочу обучить модель, чтобы она распознавала внештатные ситуации и сигнализировала об этом. Какой метод мне выбрать, как это можно сделать?  Данная модель будет своего рода фильтром для поступающего в нее потока данных.

Вот что ответили на иностранном stack:

> Absolutely, time series analysis and machine learning models are indeed appropriate for this problem, given that the sensor data is directly linked with time and the goal is to detect anomalies or emergency situations based on patterns in the time series.
>
> Choose a suitable time series machine learning model for anomaly detection. Some common approaches include:
>
> ARIMA (Autoregressive Integrated Moving Average): Suitable for stationary time series data with a clear trend and seasonality.
>
> SARIMA (Seasonal ARIMA): Extends ARIMA to handle seasonal patterns in the data.
>
> Prophet: A forecasting tool developed by Facebook for time series data with trends and seasonality.
>
> LSTM (Long Short-Term Memory) Networks: Deep learning models that can capture long-term dependencies in sequential data, suitable for time series forecasting and anomaly detection.
>
> Through the utilization of time series machine learning models, temporal trends within sensor data can be efficiently captured, abnormalities or emergency situations can be properly detected, and when needed, prompt alerts or actions may be made.

Comment: Ну это по идее детекция аномалий/выбросов. Приведите всё же какой-то пример - какие бывают варианты данных. Вообще говоря, если на давление есть какая-то установленная норма, и если давление становится вне нормы, то вы это по величине давления простым сравнением с допустимым порогом можете узнать, тут никакой модели не нужно. Вот если вы не знаете нормы или хотите ещё до достижения порога понять, что ситуация куда-то не туда развивается - это другое дело. Но опять же сферических коней в вакууме сложно разбирать, приведите конкретные примеры какие-то.

Comment: Либо, если у вас есть какие-то ещё другие данные и вы по ним хотите выявить, что скоро давление выйдет из нормы - это тоже интересная задача была бы.

Comment: Данные выглядят так 
-0.162 301
-0.142 303
-0.122 307
-0.102 305
-0.082 306
-0.062 306
-0.042 310
-0.022 308
-0.002 309
0.017 306
0.037 309
0.057 305
0.077 309
0.097 309
0.117 310
0.137 309
0.157 309
0.177 307
0.197 309
0.217 309

Comment: Время в секундах, а напротив каждого времени значение давления  с датчика в данную секунду. Значение приходит через каждые 0.02сек(шаг). Понимаю, что можно сделать на сравнении и это будет логичнее и проще, но главной задачей является именно внедрение машинного обучения. Я думаю способ работы и применения модели можно привязать по логике, чтобы был смысл ее внедрения.

Comment: Изначально я хотел обучить модель на данных при штатной ситуации и если нужно на данных на внештатной ситуации. Затем через модель пропускать уже рандомно сформированный поток данных похожий  на изначальный датасет и в режиме реального времени фильтровать этот поток и сигнализировать об отклонениях от нормы, аномалиях.

Comment: Если Вы видите какой то логичный способ организовать все эти данные ( внештатной ситуации и штатной ситуации) и обучить модель с её последующим логичным применением, то буду рад услышать, самому интересно реализовать это, но пока что не знаю какой метод выбрать, в машинном обучении новичек.

Comment: В приведённых данных особых аномалий не видно. Есть пример с аномалиями?

Comment: 3.604 235
3.624 234
3.644 234
3.664 231
3.684 230
3.704 230
3.724 229
3.744 228
3.764 227
3.784 227
3.804 225
3.825 226
3.845 225
3.865 225
3.885 227
3.905 228
3.925 228
3.945 227
3.965 227
3.985 227
4.005 224
4.024 224
4.045 223
4.064 220
4.085 221
4.104 221
40.325 445
40.344  29
40.364 278
40.385  79
40.404 123
40.425  98
40.465  79
40.484   2
40.505 494
40.525 107
40.544  76
40.565 100
40.584  80
40.605 115
40.624  56
40.645 376
40.664 127

Comment: 40.684 178
40.705 240
40.724  79
40.745  96
40.764 489
40.785   2
40.804 138
40.825 173
40.844 305
40.864 107
40.885   0
40.904 252
40.925 298
40.944  63
40.965  79
41.005  86
41.025  74
41.044 125
41.065  23
41.084  24
41.105 320
41.124  68
41.145  14
41.164 175
41.184  79
41.205 106
41.224  12
41.245  79
41.264  32
41.285 420
41.325  17
41.344 116
41.364   0
41.385 140
41.404 266
41.425   0
41.444 129
41.465 511
41.484  69
41.505 278
41.525  50
41.544 329

Comment: вот здесь идут большие скачки, так как в установку попало инородное тело, давление начало скакать, затем установка критически прекратила работу, если бы можно было сигнализировать об этом заранее и оператор это увидел, то можно было бы предпринять действия по стабилизированию ситуации

Comment: О, хорошо, я попробую с этими данными ещё. Но вообще никак тут не получается машинное обучение приделать, всё сведётся к простой математике, думаю, в итоге. Слишком простые данные.

Comment: Вы можете сами, вручную добавить какие-нибудь всевозможные нештатные данные

Comment: из перечисленных вам подходит только LSTM.  для неё это простейшая задача, поэтому потребуется очень мало узлов.  обучать надо и нормальные, и внештатные ситуации

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам пример кода без машинного обучения, чисто статистика. Берётся скользящее окно в два стандартных отклонения вверх и вниз и смотрится, где график давления пробивает эти два стандартных отклонения. Где пробил - там начало что-то не то происходить. Потом окно раздвигается в высоту, но это можно регулировать, например, шириной окна. Если окно будет очень широкое, то инерция у него будет больше, оно не так сильно будет расти в высоту.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

n = 100
t = np.linspace(1, 10, n)
p = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(n)) + 200 + (np.mod(t, 2) == 0).astype(int) * 5
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': t,
    'pressure': p
})
window = 12
no_of_std = 2
rolling_mean = df['pressure'].rolling(window).mean()
rolling_std = df['pressure'].rolling(window).std()
df['high'] = (rolling_mean + (rolling_std * no_of_std)).bfill()
df['low'] = (rolling_mean - (rolling_std * no_of_std)).bfill()
df['alert'] = np.nan
df.loc[(df['pressure'] > df['high']) | (df['pressure'] < df['low']), 'alert'] = df['pressure']
#df.iloc[:window, -1] = np.nan
plt.figure()
sns.lineplot(x='time', y='pressure', data=df, color='green', alpha=0.5)
sns.lineplot(x='time', y='high', data=df, color='cyan', alpha=0.5)
sns.lineplot(x='time', y='low', data=df, color='cyan', alpha=0.5)
sns.scatterplot(x='time', y='alert', data=df, color='red', alpha=0.5)
plt.ylim(180, 220)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не передать словами, как я вам благодарен, интерес к данной сфере взлетел еще больше!!!